# How to display a binary image in pictureBox VC++

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, bitmap

i'm working on a VC++ and OpenCV application, i'm loading images into picturBox and make some OpenCV operations on them, i assign the loaded image into IplImage to make processing on it but then assign the processed image again into the picture box, i write this code to load the image selected from openFileDialog into IplImage ,binarize the image then reassign the binarized image back to the pictureBox
code:

```
const char* fileName = (const char*)(void*)
   Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(openFileDialog1->FileName);
             IplImage *img=cvLoadImage(fileName,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
             int width=img->width;
             int height=img->height;
             IplImage *grayScaledImage=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
             cvCvtColor(img,grayScaledImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);
cvThreshold(grayScaledImage,grayScaledImage,128,256,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
this->pictureBox1->Image=(gcnew 
System::Drawing::Bitmap(grayScaledImage->width,grayScaledImage->height,grayScaledImage->widthStep, 
System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)grayScaledImage->imageData));
```

but i doesn't find a format which displays a binary image, any help about that.

Original Image:
[image]

Converted image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be creating an RGB image (System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb) but copying into it a grayscale, presumably the System::Drawing::Imaging function doesn't do conversion - or isn't doing it properly.

Edit: Some more explanation.
Your greyscale image is stored in memory as one byte for each pixel Y0, Y1, Y2,Y3...... Y639 (we use Y for brightness, and assuming a 640 pixel wide image).

You have told the .net image class that this is Format24bppRgb which would be stored as one red,one green and blue byte per pixel (3bytes =  24bpp). So the class takes your image data and assumes that Y0,Y1,Y2 are the red,green,blue values for he first pixel, Y3,Y4,Y5 for the next and so on.
This is using up 3x as many bytes as your image has, so after 1/3 of the row it starts reading the next row and so on - which gives you the three repeated pictures.

ps. the fact that you have turned it into a binary image just means that the Y values are either 0 or 255 - it doesn't change the data size or shape.

Comment: how doesn't System::Drawing::Imaging make conversions and the image dispalyed in the pictureBox?

Comment: @Eslam if you want a greyscale image in the .net box then tell it to use a greyscale pixel type rather than 24bppRgb

Comment: i tried to use Format16bppGrayScale but it throws an exception

Comment: @Eslam you are giving system::drawing... an 8bit greyscale which  it doesn't support. Why not give it the colour image?

Comment: i'm not giving system::drawing a grayscale image i'm giving it a binary image, because i want to binarize my original image and load the output in the picturebox

Comment: ok, now i want to display a binary image in the pictureBox, what can i do, i tried all the formats but no one displays binary image properly!!

Comment: @Eslam use cvtcolor again to convert gray back to rgb cvCvtColor(grayScaledImage,img,CV_GRAY2RGB) and pass img

Comment: but it will be displayed as true color image not binary!!